# PeerJs Invalid key provided

Tags: node.js, peerjs

I'm using my own `peerjs` server it's running without any errors and also connection as working but on clinet console i'm getting error **Invalid key provided**

```
var peer = new Peer({host: 'domain.com', port: 3000, path: '/peerjs',debug: 3});
```

and here is log

```
peer.js:1476 PeerJS:  Socket open
peer.js:1476 PeerJS:  ERROR Aborting!
peer.js:1476 PeerJS:  ERROR Error: Invalid key provided
(index):22 Peer error Error: Invalid key provided
    at Peer.emitError (peer.js:1070)
    at Peer._abort (peer.js:1063)
    at Peer._handleMessage (peer.js:883)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (peer.js:809)
    at Socket.emit (peer.js:1802)
    at WebSocket._socket.onmessage (peer.js:1252)
peer.js:1476 PeerJS:  Socket closed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need a key. If you look at the peerjs-server documentation here https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server

You will see the command line to start the peerjs server:

```
$> peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs
```

It's not obvious, but it's running it with a key of "peerjs".

The client code, peer.js, defaults the key to "peerjs" if you don't provide one.

So the key is optional if you run the server properly :)